# iOS storing an 'access_token' throughout the app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to determine the best way for me to store, and access an Access token in use of an iOS app.
I'm getting myself familiar with Core data, and while this has proved beneficial for some parts of the app's data, i'm not sure core data is best for what i need for the token.

Most views rely on some simple network request to our API. The access token is used with these requests to authenticate and authorize the data content requested. 

To explain better here, an example of how it would be used is within the `AppDelegate.m`. on `applicaion:hasFinishedLoadingWithOptions` i preform a simple check to confirm the token with the API, on success the view is changed to the 'main menu', and on failure, view is changed to the login view.

This token needs to be accessed in most views as at any point the API voids the token, the user will have to re-login to attain a new token (not regularly).

My intial thought is to impement a `token.h` which i can call in ViewControllers where needed, however as this is my first large iOS app i would feel better with some constructive critism, tips or hints about how best to access this token, 'globally' as if it were a static value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it in keychain like this
Apple has written an Objective-C wrapper that you can use to simplify working with the keychain, the files in the wrapper are KeychainItemWrapper.h and KeychainItemWrapper.m, both are included in the attached Xcode project.

```
UITextField *accesstoken = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 240, 30)];
[accesstoken setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestAppLoginData" accessGroup:nil];
```

Writing to the Keychain-

// Store AcessToken to keychain

```
Nsstring *strAcessToken=@"abcd" 
[keychain setObject:strAcessToken forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

Reading from the Keychain-

// Get AcessToken from keychain (if it exists)

```
[accesstoken setText:[keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount]];
```

Notes:

```
Writing and retrieving values from the keychain doesn’t seem to work in the simulator.
Uninstalling an application will not remove the items from the keychain. If you run the demo application on your device, and uninstall the app, the username and password will remain in the keychain (a firmware reset will, of course, remove the keychain values).
```

Comment: how about using `NSUserDefaults` against `KeychainItemWrapper`?

Comment: In KeychainItemWrapper the data is persistent even after app uninstall-install but not in case of NSUserDefaults. So it depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Although is question is highly drawn to have only opinionated answer I will give my point of view on the subject.

You need an API client, which hold the acces token, every time an new view controller is create it should get a reference to this API client. Or if you are not comfortable with pass it every time you might implement the API client a singleton.

All server API class should be via this API client, which should handle the network and API calls.
[`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is great example of how this can be done.

The access token it self should be stored in the [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html), because this is the place to stored these kind of thing.

Comment: Isn't the access token *transient* in nature and therefore it's unnecessary to store it externally at all?

Comment: i debated asking this on programmers.stackexchange but recently i've come across a lot of opinion-based questions on stackoverflow, of which are not voted down or haulted. 

with regard to your answer, i feel this is a much better idea than what i had. up until now each view has handled its own network transactions

Comment: Big tip, keep your view controllers code to a minimum, split up a much and you think is needed. Like create separate classes for datasource, network connection, model, data acces components, etc... this wil make you code easy to maintain and easy to understand. Just don't make it to abstract. There are no really set rules for it and it up to you as a developers to setup something you are comfortable with.

Answer (score -3):

You can store your token in the `NSUserDefaults`

```
+(void)saveToken:(NSString *)token{
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

+(NSString *)getToken{
  return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"token"];
}
```

Comment: Firstly user defaults are for storing app preferences and secondly it stores the data in an external file, when in-memory storage is sufficient.

Comment: well token is something which maintain the session which is gunna change the every time you login or your token is flushed on server end.

Comment: So you agree that it only needs to be stored in-memory, and not externally.

Comment: But it should not be stored in the user default, it's not save there. Store it in the keychain.